# React-native yarn workspaces/wml don't load imported modules that contains an installed package

Tags: reactjs, react-native, yarn-workspaces, wml

I tried to implement react-native with workspaces to share the business logic across mobile and web application, it works well on the web, but it doesn't work or even load files on react-native. I ended up using wml but it cannot load a file from the shared package that's importing packages like axios or so.., although these packages are already installed there, and it works as expected on web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) instead of yarn workSpaces / wml